# Mongo's load() doesn't work with tilde paths?

Tags: mongodb, shell

Newcomer to mongo scripts and stumped on something rather basic. I am doing some automation with the mongo shell and need to load some information that's in a dotfile in the current users home directory. This is on Mac OS X.

I am calling the load function like so:

```
load("~/.config.js")
```

When I do this, mongo returns this error:

```
file [~/.config.js] doesn't exist
```

If I type the path out by hand, e.g:

```
load("/Users/foo/.config.js")
```

The command works and the data is loaded as I expect. The problem with this approach is that this script needs to be re-runnable across multiple machines, so hard-coding the path isn't an option. Looking through the mongo documentation I haven't found a way to expand the path or call a shell command so I can detect the current users name.

I guess if I have to the config file can be moved to a global directory like `/etc` but that seems really bad to me. Is it really possible that mongo can't expand shell paths?

Comment: Uhh...if you're going to downvote this question you should minimally leave a comment explaining what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load` does accept relative paths like `/scripts/my_scripts.js`. What it doesn't do is expand shell abbreviations like ~ into paths. You can put in full paths or path relative to the current working directory of the shell.

You can find more information at the following two links:

1. [Scripting in the mongo shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#execute-a-javascript-file)
2. [native functions in the mongo shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/#native)

As a workaround for your case, you may able to shell script hack in expansion of a shortcut like ~ by getting the shell to expand the shortcut, inserting the expansion into a .js file in the `load` call, and then having the script be executed by mongo at startup.

Comment: That's pretty lame - I feel like shell expansion is a very basic feature. I'm accepting your answer since it helps confirm my suspicions. I worked around the issue by symlinking the ~/.config.js file in a different build script to a relative path that the mongo script could pick up. Not beautiful, but it works for now.

Comment: @bitops: If you have any feature suggestion such as this, feel free to raise in the MongoDB Jira project (ideally checking there isn't already a similar feature request to upvote/watch). I've added one for this feature, if you want to add any extra comments: [SERVER-16070: Add tilde path support to load()](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16070).

Comment: First link is broken :(